# NoReverseMatch error while adding slug in url path

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

i'm building a blog app in django. In the blog list page after preview of each button i've added Read More link to read the blog in details. I'm trying to add slug in the blog detail page but it gives the NoReverse error.

I get this error:

[image: error]

This is my urls.py of blog_app and i've included in main project url.py:

```
app_name = 'blog_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.BlogList.as_view(), name='blog_list'),
    path('write/', views.CreateBlog.as_view(), name='create_blog'),
    path('details/<slug:slug>/', views.blog_details, name='blog_details'),

]
```

This is the views.py:

```
def blog_list(request):
    return render(request, 'blog_app/blog_list.html', context={})


class BlogList(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'blogs'
    model = Blog
    template_name ='blog_app/blog_list.html'
    


class CreateBlog(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog_app/create_blog.html'
    fields = ('blog_title', 'blog_content', 'blog_image')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        blog_object = form.save(commit=False)
        blog_object.author = self.request.user
        title = blog_object.blog_title
        blog_object.slug = title.replace(' ', '-') + '-' + str(uuid.uuid4())
        blog_object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))



def blog_details(request, slug):
    blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)

    return render(request, 'blog_app/blog_details.html', context={'blog':blog})
```

This is models.py:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_author')
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=264, verbose_name='Assign a Title')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=264, unique=True)
    blog_content = models.TextField(verbose_name="What's on your Mind")
    blog_image =models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images', verbose_name="Blog Image")
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-published_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title
```

This is blog_details.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Blog Details {% endblock title %} 

{%block body_block %}
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>{‌{ blog.blog_title }}</h2>
            <h4>Posted By: {‌{ blog.author }}</h4>
            <i><h6>Published On: {‌{ blog.published_date}}</h6></i>
            <i><h6>Updated On: {‌{ blog.update_date }}</h6></i>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="/media/{‌{ blog.blog_image }}" width="100%">
        </div>

        {‌{ blog.blog_content | linebreaks }}

    </div>
{% endblock body_block %}
```

This is blog_list.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load custom_filters %}

{% block title %} Home {% endblock title %} 

{% block body_block %}


{% for blog in blogs %}

<h2>{‌{ blog.blog_title }}</h2>
<h6><i>{‌{ blog.published_date }}</i></h6>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="/media/{‌{ blog.blog_image }}" alt="{‌{ blog.blog_title }}" width="100%">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <p>
            {‌{ blog.blog_content | range_filter  | linebreaks }}
            <a href="{% url 'blog_app:blog_details' slug=blog.slug %}">Read More</a>
        </p>
        
        <h6>Posted By: <a href="">{‌{ blog.author }}</a></h6>
    </div>

</div> 

{% endfor %}

{% endblock body_block %}
```

This is the traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in 
rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 
61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, 
in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse 
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "E:\ProIde\1 - Django Developer Path\Django Blog Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'blog_details' with keyword arguments '{'slug': "Authorities-Take-Down-World's-Largest-Illegal-Dark-Web-Marketplace-1cf46a73-4daf-4d94-8db6-faa7c559535b"}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/details/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

How to resolve the errror?

Comment: Your `Authorities-Take-Down-World’ s-Langest-Tllegel-Dark-Web-Marketplace-1cfasa73-4daf-4d94-Sdb6-fea7eS595356` is not a slug, a sl7ug does not contain an accent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your construct invalid slugs. The slug

```
...Authorities-Take-Down-World's-...
```

is not a valid slug, since it contains an apostrophe (`'`) between `World` and `s`.

It is not a good idea to construct a slug yourself. Django has a [**`slugify(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) to construct a slug:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class CreateBlog(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog_app/create_blog.html'
    fields = ('blog_title', 'blog_content', 'blog_image')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        title = form.cleaned_data['blog_title']
        form.instance.slug = f'{slugify(title)}-{uuid.uuid4()}'
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

You will need to remove the record with the invalid slug, or update it with a valid slug.

Comment: Thnx, I've removed the titles with (') and it worked. But how to slugify in those condition?

Comment: @tapas: as said, just use the `slugify` function. This is a function in the Django package that normally should transform a string to a valid slug. Please do *not* use custom text processing.

Comment: @tapas: Django will convert the string to `authorities-take-down-worlds-...`, so it will remove invalid characters.